# Style certain characters with CSS

Tags: css

I'm assuming it's not possible, but just in case it is or someone has a nice trick up their sleeves, is there a way to target certain characters using CSS?

For example make all letters `z` in paragraphs red, or in my particular case set `vertical-align:sup` on all `7` in elements marked with the class `chord`.

Comment: How about processing the text with JavaScript and adding `span` elements with some class?

Comment: no. you would need to use javascript or some preprocessing to add classes to span wrapped characters

Comment: In pure CSS, the only selector vaguely similar to what you ask is `:first-letter`

Comment: Yeah, doing it on the backend is my fallback solution which will be ok, but would've preferred it if there was a clean CSS solution

Comment: Looks it's possible to use [custom fonts specific to certain (unicode code-point-specified) characters](https://css-tricks.com/modifying-specific-letters-with-css-and-javascript/) via `@font-face`, which might be close... and possibly combined with the `font-style` descriptor to do exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's not possible in CSS. Your only option would be [`first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) and that's not going to cut it. Either use JavaScript or (as you stated in your comments), your server-side language.

Comment: Seems the answer would be `no`, yes :) I'll accept this when I'm allowed to. I'm already parsing chords in the backend so just have to adjust the output. Just wondered if there was a way the output could remain `<span class="c">B7</span>` instead of `<span class="c">B<span class="7">7</span></span>`, which is quite a number of characters just to style two characters :p

Comment: @Svish Yeah it is pretty hefty, but you are styling chords so that's never going to be the most straightforward thing to achieve :). Hey, don't let a couple of extra `span` tags ruin your chords :)

Comment: @Svish Since you have only two letters to style, I suppose using both `<span class="c">B7</span>` and `first-letter` you could could accomplish what you want.

Comment: @xpy that would work if all songs only consisted of B7 chords ;) Unfortunately the 7 can be in a lot of different places and what comes after the first letter can be, and usually is, something else than a 7 :/

Comment: I may be pushing this a lot but, you could also do something like `<span data-chord="b-7">B7</span>` and the you could select any chord to style with `[data-chord]`, `[data-chord^=b]`, `[data-chord$=7]`, etc.

Comment: That looks like quite a pain :p

Comment: is there a rest-letters?

Answer (score 38):

Hi I know you said in CSS but as everybody told you, you can't, this is a javascript solution, just my 2 cents.

best...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LSrk/)

*css*

```
span.highlight{
   background:#F60;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
}

p{
   font-family:Verdana;   
}
```

*html*

```
<p>
    Let's go Zapata let's do it for the revolution, Zapatistas!!!   
</p>
```

*javascript*

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {    
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
    });
};

$("p").highlight("Z","highlight");
```

***Result***
[image]

Comment: This is a great solution – Any chance you could update the regex so it does not target the character within attributes? It's breaking a link's href attribute because there's a matching character in the URL linked to. Thanks!

Comment: are you passing a complete block of text, which contains links inside of it?

Comment: Yes, when applied to paragraphs. Looks like I avoided the issue by only hitting capital V instead of all v characters, and making sure there were no capital V in any links. I used this to tighten awkward kerning/letter-spacing.

Comment: what is the "gi" here in RegExp(str, "gi")?

Comment: I think regular expressions are an extremely brittle solution here:
what if you the str you're replacing happens to also occur in interior markup?

    `<p>Let's go Zapata <em class="SNOOZE">pizza?</em></p>`

(or, `highlight('m',…)` which would match the `m` from any `em` tags etc)

Hence the adage "if you have a problem, and solve it with regexps, you now have two problems" :-(

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it in CSS is to wrap them in a span and give the span a class. Then target all spans with that class.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to @ncubica but too long for a comment, here's a version that doesn't use regular expressions and doesn't alter any DOM nodes other than Text nodes.  Pardon my CoffeeScript.

```
# DOM Element.nodeType:
NodeType =
  ELEMENT:    1
  ATTRIBUTE:  2
  TEXT:       3
  COMMENT:    8

# Tags all instances of text `target` with <span class=$class>$target</span>
#
jQuery.fn.tag = (target, css_class)->
  @contents().each (index)->
    jthis = $ @
    switch @.nodeType
      when NodeType.ELEMENT
        jthis.tag  target, css_class
      when NodeType.TEXT
        text = jthis.text()
        altered = text.replaceAll  target, "<span class=\"#{css_class}\">$&</span>"
        if altered isnt text
          jthis.replaceWith  altered

($ document).ready ->
  ($ 'div#page').tag '⚀', 'die'
```

Comment: CoffeeScript is the best JavaScript, nothing to be ashamed of!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it only works with regular characters/letters. For example: what if we want to highlight all asterisk (\u002A) symbols on page. Tried 
`$("p").highlight("u\(u002A)","highlight");`in js and inserted `&#42;` in html but it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

As many referred "That's not possible in CSS.", and the plain JavaScript code is generally faster and uses fewer resources compared to the *jQuery* code.

#### Plain JavaScript solution

```js
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
const substringToHighlight = "sz"; // the substring to be highlighted
const regex = new RegExp(substringToHighlight, "gi");
for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  const paragraph = paragraphs[i];
  const text = paragraph.innerHTML;
  const newText = text.replace(regex, (match) => {
    return `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`;
  });
  paragraph.innerHTML = newText;
}
```

```css
span.highlight{
   background:#F60;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
}

p {
    font-family: 'BeingHumannormalhuman';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org//face/being-human" type="text/css"/>

<p>
    Let's go Szeklers let's do it for the freedom of Szeklerland!!!
</p>
```