# Colouring a specific character through CSS

Tags: html, css

What I am after is to colour in just one character of my code throughout the page.

The lines between each of the words are what I would like to be a different colour from the rest of the text but I would like to do this in CSS rather than horribly adding  to each one just to change its colour.

> Anti-virus End Point | Disk Encryption | UTM | Email and Web Security

Is it possible through CSS?

here is what I have attempted but I don't think I'm coming close.

```
  | {
     color:#00FF00;
     }
```

Comment: I think you need to use javascript for this

Comment: The character would have to be enclosed in a `<span>` or other tag for this to be possible with pure CSS. Is it? Can you show the HTML source code?

Comment: @Pekka Yeah that does the job. A little more fiddly than I wanted because I have to add "<span>" to everything but it nicer than adding "<font color=...>"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style certain characters with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091469/style-certain-characters-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap each of the | character in a span with a class you can use that:

```
<span class="separator">|</span>

.separator {
    color: #0F0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be encapsulating the text (not the separators) inside `<span/>`s, and use `:after` pseudo-element to create the separator.

Then, specify that, for the last element, the separator is not required:

HTML

```
<div class="separator">
    <span>Anti-virus End Point</span>
    <span>Disk Encryption</span>
    <span>UTM</span>
    <span>Email and Web Security</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.separator > span:not(:nth-last-child(1)):after {
    content: ' | ';
    color:#00FF00;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j9kZS/1/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no pure CSS solution for this. If you are using jQuery it would probably be easiest to make use of the highlight plugin for this:
http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Vbc/2/

css

```
 .divider {
     color:#00FF00;
     }
```

html

```
try <span class="divider">|</span> try
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with pure `js`:

```
<style>
    .paint{
        color: #00FF00;
    }
</style>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
        var str = "Anti-virus End Point | Disk Encryption | UTM | Email and Web Security";
        str = str.split('|').join('<span class="paint">|</span>');
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```