# css selector for character

Tags: html, css

I have a span with a text:

```
<span class="magic">a sample text</span>
```

is it possible to create selector that will change the color of every symbol 'a' or ' '

```
.magic...<something> {
   color: red;
}
```

note: I do not want to surround every character with additional span - I know this will work

Comment: There are currently no selectors for this. You would need JS to do it dynamically.

Comment: Its is funny because in your example you can use the pseudo-element [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/::first-letter). Something like this `.magic:first-letter { color: red; }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style certain characters with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091469/style-certain-characters-with-css)

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do this with CSS only, since it doesn't provide any selectors for this. Fortunately you can use javascript and regex instead.

Here's a example of jquery code that will replace every "a" character that's inside a `p` element with `<span class="red">a</span>` so it can be styled differently (I found this code somewhere here, in stackoverflow, and adapted it to your needs):

```
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/a/g, '<span class="red">a</span>'));
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/v42QW/3/)

Comment: It's a pseudo-element - hence the double colons.

Comment: I've removed the pseudo-element part since it don't really answers the question, just creates another problem. I think the best solution to this question is to use jquery to replace any specified character.

Comment: Your JSFiddle should probably reflect the code you have here. Just a thought.

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle to reflect the code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with CSS, I've actually been looking for something quite similair.
This is what I found a short while back: (jQuery plugin)

http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

You can start with certain characters highlighted upon pageload... The documentation provided is not that hard to follow if you have some expecience.