# CSS for 1 character in words

Tags: css

I lost 20h to fix the problem due to CSS. Please help me.
I want font to 1 character in words, Eg:

```
How to Format<br>
How to Code<br>
How to Debug<br>
How to Test<br>
and more
```

I want write CSS font-family to character \'g\' in all my code html, not for all, i don't know how to code this.
Please help me, thank you for reading

Comment: On my knowleges... you can not... you might achive this by putting all the g on the span and use document.getelementByclassname or make a new font that only contains g.

Comment: answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091469/style-certain-characters-with-css

Comment: I understand English is not your mother tongue but it's very difficult to figure out what you mean. Do you want to render the letters `g` scattered in your text using a different font than the rest of the paragraph?

Comment: If you want to style one particular character in your text using a special font you'll want to replace each occurrence of *letter* with `<span class="your-special-class">letter</span>` using either JavaScript, on client side, after page rendered or using your server's language (php, java, javascript), when providing the page. Now you can apply any style rules to `.your-special-class`, with CSS.

Comment: @Thái - I think I understand the question, but can you show an example? What did you try? How should it look like? It is really `g`, or something else (another language)?

Comment: my language so bad, sorry all, but i see example and that's what I need. thanks all

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change **just the font**, for a **specific character**, this can be achieved with CSS using [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontForG';
  src: local('Times New Roman');
  unicode-range: U+67, U+47;
}

div {
  font-family: FontForG, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<div>
Three gray green greedy geese,<br />
Feeding on a weedy piece,<br />
The piece was weedy,<br />
And the geese were greedy,<br />
Three gray-green greedy geese.<br />
</div>
```

`unicode-range` is very limited, and is for applying different fonts for different languages or for emoji.

Comment: I don't know if that is exactly what they asked for (difficult to guess), but I like the way you did it !