# How to break a sentence into different parts in css

Tags: css

I want to break a sentence in 3 parts using css, e.g., `United States ("US") - Tax reforms`

Here I want to name 3 parts from the sentence.

- name: `United States`
- symbol: `US`
- subject: `Tax reforms`

I know I can use `("` to yield name, `("` and `")` to yield symbol, and `") -` to yield subject. But I don't know how to.

I looked up on "word-break" but it doesn't seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: CSS won't do this, you'd need code.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know regardless.

Comment: @Karma Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. Add the code you have and explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot use CSS for splitting a string into parts.** You simply cannot target single letters with CSS (except for the first letter with the `:first-letter` pseudo class). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16091559/3233827) for more information on this subject.

You could use JavaScript combined with e.g. a regular expression. A simple example would be the following (just as a reminder: do not parse user-content directly as HTML for security reasons):

```js
const input = 'United States ("US") - Tax reforms';
const regex = /^([\w\s]+)\s\("(\w+)"\)\s-\s([\w ]+)/;
const result = regex.exec(input);

if (result !== null) {
  const resultingObject = {
    name: result[1],
    symbol: result[2],
    subject: result[3]
  };
  console.log(resultingObject);
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p class="name">${resultingObject.name}</p>
    <p class="symbol">${resultingObject.symbol}</p>
    <p class="subject">${resultingObject.subject}</p>`;
}
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.symbol {
  font-style: italic;
}
.subject {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```