# How do I style certain characters/words differently in CSS/js? without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to select all of the commas in an HTML document to change their color. As far as I can tell this is not possible with CSS alone. My best guess is to use js to find and replace `,` with `<span class='comma'>,</span>` but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do this for every element, it will be slow. Not like it can't be done, but it would be nice to at least have a parent container where you can search.

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <p>Some more, elements here.</p>
  <span>Some</span> have, commas.
</div>
```

```js
container = document.querySelector('.my-container')
html = container.innerHTML
newHTML = html.replace(/,/g, '<span class="comma">,</span>')
container.innerHTML = newHTML
```

```css
.comma {
  color: red;
}
```

You can see it running [here](https://codepen.io/gosukiwi/pen/LYWOgeK).

If you **really** want to apply it to the whole document just replace the contents of `document.body` rather than `container`.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably depend on how long the page is - [gosuwiki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767996/10940584) with JavaScript is most likely the easiest way for a relatively small file, but this would be run every time the page is loaded, which isn't usually optimal for larger pages or ones that are loaded often. Depending on your project's needs, it might be best to just run a find and replace operation in your IDE (or via a short script) to swap out the commas for `<span>`s. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16091469/10940584) might also be of some interest to you - the answers seem to agree that such a selection cannot be done with pure CSS.