# In CSS, can I apply an alternative font-feature-setting style to a single letter?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to apply a different style (using `font-feature-settings: 'aalt';`) for a single letter type: an uppercase R.
As expected, the whole `div` that has the style applied gets changed to the stylistic alternate.
Is there a way to get it to work on just the R?

Comment: Do you mean all uppercase `R`s in the page text?

Comment: You need to share some code in order to get a proper answer. Anyways, this kind of thing often means isolating the character in a way, perhaps like: `<span class="mySpecialStyle">R</span>`

Comment: `<span></span>` is what you're looking for: An inline element to apply CSS on the content inside it.

Comment: [Style certain characters with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091469/style-certain-characters-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get it to work on just the R?

Apply the style only to the letters that you want to stylize:

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
.line { display: block; line-height: 1.5rem; }
.stylized { color: red; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span class="stylized">R</span>ow, <span class="stylized">R</span>ow, <span class="stylized">R</span>ow Your Boat</h1>
  <p>
    <span class="line"><span class="stylized">R</span>ow, row, row your boat,</span>
    <span class="line">Gently down the stream.</span>
    <span class="line">Merrily, merrily, merrily, merrily,</span>
    <span class="line">Life is but a dream.</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Also there's a special [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) if you want to style first latter in e.g. a chapter

Comment: Ahhh I thought about splitting it into ```spans```... but was hopeful that maybe there was a simple character-targeted cool CSS rule I didn't know about. Might have to implement it like that or simply drop the feature.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: `<span>`'s ARE the primary way to target a single character. You never specified it would be for a first-letter, in that case you could use the CSS rule @BANOnotIT mentioned in the earlier comment. Beyond all this you'd have to use Javascript.