# How to select and stylize multiple line before specific character with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have these example line in my HTML.

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Name : John</li>
        <li>Age : 32</li>
        <li>Gender : Male</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Is it possible to select & stylize text before colon only and all leave text after colon unaffected with CSS?

I can't manually insert span of each line because my actual list is way much longer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style certain characters with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091469/style-certain-characters-with-css)

Comment: Have you considered using "find and replace" in your IDE? This can't be done with only HTML and CSS, though it can certainly be done using JavaScript (if that's acceptable)?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add span, just like this

```css
.my-list li span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="my-list">
        <li><span>Name</span> : John</li>
        <li><span>Age</span> : 32</li>
        <li><span>Gender</span> : Male</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Problem is i have so many list, and manually wrap each line with span is kinda difficult.

Comment: you can use multiline find replace on your editor
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEPN24Sg0SY

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like this solution, you may have to use javascript to accomplish what you're wanting, but here is an idea.

Add a class to your `<ul>` element like this.
Then remove the **"Name:"**, **"Age:"**, and **"Gender:"** text from each `li` tag.

```
<body>
    <ul class="modifyText">
        <li>John</li>
        <li>32</li>
        <li>Male</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Then add this to your CSS file. This way you can just copy and paste and change the `nth-child` and the `content` without manually doing each one.

```
.modifyText li:nth-child(1)::before  {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bolder;
 content: "Name: ";
}
.modifyText li:nth-child(2)::before  {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bolder;
 content: "Age: ";
}
.modifyText li:nth-child(3)::before  {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bolder;
 content: "Gender: ";
}
```